# You can only create a user with a password in a contained database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using  a contained database, after creating the database I attempted to create a user but I got the error:

> You can only create a user with a password in a contained database

My code is:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

```
CREATE DATABASE [MyDb]
CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL
ON PRIMARY
( NAME = N'My', FILENAME = N'C:\My.mdf')
LOG ON
( NAME = N'My_log', FILENAME =N'C:\My_log.ldf')
```

```
CREATE USER MyUser
WITH PASSWORD = 'pass@123';
GO
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In **SQL Server 2017**, I found that my initial setup did not configure the ["contained databases"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable) feature to help this along.

so, at server level you can check the server properties in the UI or run:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'CONTAINED DATABASE AUTHENTICATION'
```

if the running value isn't 1, then:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'CONTAINED DATABASE AUTHENTICATION', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

At the database level, it also might not have the "contained database" feature fully enabled. The option sits in the Database Properties panel on the Options section, the fourth dropdown at the top...

> Containment type == None or Partial

You can set it via SQL too. eg:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDb] SET CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL
GO
```

thereafter, you can create the contained user as suggested by [@aleksandr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085940/aleksandr-fedorenko)

```
USE [MyDb]
GO
CREATE USER MyUser WITH PASSWORD = 'pass@123';
GO
```

Comment: Worked in MS SQL 2019. 
To find 'Containment type' in Server Management Studio right click on database name -> Properties -> Options

Answer (score 71):

Create the login and the user separately:

```
CREATE LOGIN MyUser WITH PASSWORD = 'pass@123';
CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN MyUser;
```

The names can be the same but of course they can also be different.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer, it worked without messing with any configuration.

Comment: The question is about contained database users, so whilst this answer might work for some it's not correct for a contained database, which does not use users based on logins.

Answer (score 10):

I think your current database is [master], but you have to use [MyDb]

```
USE [MyDb]
GO
CREATE USER MyUser
WITH PASSWORD = 'pass@123';
GO
```

Comment: You may need same database configuration:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/creating-user-for-a-single-contained-database/20428#20428?newreg=f9bfaa5987564bbb8fd931f782eea4ef

Comment: Doesn't work on MSSQL server 2017. still says the same error.